# finding the process numbers of a multithread application

Tags: linux, bash, process

How can I retrieve the process numbers of a issued multithread application? I mean, I am looking for a bash script that after executing a command, puts the process numbers in a list. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
./run_program -nt 4
# find the list of PIDs
```

Comment: `pstree -p $SOME_PID`

Comment: @xxfelixxx `pstree -p $$`

Comment: `pstree` shows a graphical view. I just want the PIDs (the numbers)

Comment: A multithreaded process only has *one* process ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pgrep` for checking the process ids.

If you're only looking at child PID of the current process, you can use the `-P` option:

```
pgrep -P $$
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `run_program` creates same execute path in ps pid list.

```
ARRAY=($(ps -fe | grep run_program | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' ORS=' '))
```

and you can access in example

```
echo ${ARRAY[2]}
```